# Intellisense not working in Visual Studio 2010 for jQuery widget when base is specified

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2010, widget, intellisense

I have problems with getting the intellisense fully work for my jQuery widgets in Visual Studio 2010. For a widget the intellisense works fine when no base is specified.

But when I do specify a base the intellisense stops working :-(

In the following code intellisense works:

```js
/// <reference path="/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.js" />

(function ($) {
    /// <param name="$" type="jQuery">Pass jQuery</param>
    $.widget("space.baseWidget", {
        _create: function () {
            /// <summary>
            /// The constructor of the widget
            /// </summary>
            if (this._doStuff("value1", { value2: true })) {
                alert("Ughly alert in widget constructor");
            }
        },

        _doStuff: function (param1, param2) {
            /// <summary>
            /// Actually do nothing and just say you did
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="param1" type="String">Some text</param>
            /// <param name="param2" type="Object">Some object</param>
            /// <returns type="Bool">Always true</returns>
            return true;
        }
    });
} (jQuery));
```

Screen shot:

(I would like to add a screenshot here, but my reputation is not good enough (yet), so you have to trust me on my blue eyes that intellisense works for above code)

When I change:

```js
    $.widget("space.baseWidget", {
```

To:

```js
    $.widget("space.extendedWidget", space.baseWidget, {
```

No more intellisense... 
Does anybody has a idea why? Or even better, how to fix it? Thanx in advance!